# Gemfile issues and Ruby install issues

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, uninstallation, pik

I am working on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I had Ruby version `2.1.5` installed on my machine and everything was working great.  I went and installed a gem that would set up a project for you with most of the basics already completed, but it required Ruby `2.2.2`.  I went and researched how to upgrade my Ruby version and the best solution I found was to install the `Pik` gem for windows and install `2.2.2` separately, and switch between the two versions.

I followed a tutorial on YouTube for how to set up Pik.  I normally use Git Bash but the tutorial required me to use the cmd.exe prompt to set up Pik, and then it included a way to use Pik with Git Bash at the end of the tutorial.  I also had to add a file to my `PATH` in the system settings.

I was able to set up Pik and everything worked great with Pik on both the cmd.exe and Git Bash consoles.  However, from there if I went to run any other commands such as `bundle install`, I would get an error:

> Could not locate gemfile.

I have also experienced the same error, but it would say something along the lines of an issue with the `.bundle/directory`.  I tried switching to a project that I had already created in the past and tried running the command again. It still had the same error. (I did this to see if the gemfile in the project would fix anything.) If I try running `gem install rails`, I have had it work once or twice - but I still have the 'no gemfile' issue after the fact.

The times the command doesn't work I often get:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed
>   (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz).

I tried running the pik gem and pik gemsync commands to see if that would fix my issues but it did not.

I tried uninstalling Pik by doing the pik implode command and deleting the files it created.  The issue still persisted.  I tried uninstalling the `2.2.2` version of Ruby using the uninstall executable in the file, and deleting any left over file(s).  The issue still persisted.  I tried to uninstall and reinstall Ruby completely from my machine, the 2.1.5 version that is doing the same method as the 2.2.2 version.  Yet the issue still persists no matter what I do.  I have tried many times uninstalling and reinstalling both Ruby versions, from the executable and from the control panel.  I would like to find a way to completely uninstall and reinstall all of Ruby if possible, preferably reinstall Ruby `2.2.2`.  Or if anyone else has any other ideas for how to fix this issue?

Comment: It's great you add detail, but can you please add a short (no more than 4 - 5 line) summary at the top that summarizes your issue. With the number of questions on the site, making it difficult to spot the issue you are facing will make readers just move on to the next question. Also try and break up your paragraphs so the information is easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from there if I went to run any other commands such as bundle install I would get an error Could not locate `Gemfile`.

As you've guessed, you need a file named `gemfile` in the same location you are running `bundle install` from

> If I try running `gem install rails` I have had it work once or twice but I still have the no gemfile issue after the fact.

Running `gem install <package>` doesn't create a gemfile for you. You need to do this yourself. It's essentially a file where you manually specify which packages you would like your project to use. See [here on how to create](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html).

> The times the command doesn't work I often get: "ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed ( https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)."

This sometimes happens on Windows machine. You can do a quick search on how to fix the gem command with SSL, or in your `Gemfile` you can temporarily specify `http://rubygems.org/` instead of `https://rubygems.org/`

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to have fixed my issue.